# Java 7u55 Security warning Issue

Tags: java, applet, windows-xp, security-warning

I'm using jzebra **signed** version on one of my systems to print labels.

There was an issue where applet was not loading on windows XP machine.
When checked the java version was old(7u45) and I updated it to 7u55.

Now a strange issue has started occuring on that system.

[image: Java Security Warning]

This message appears when ever I try to print any labels.

As you can see the warning is not complete, it states **Java Application Above**, where there is no information above.

I have already tried

setting security to medium,

adding url to exception and

setting **enable-hide warning and run with protections** in **mixed mode**

There is no issue on the win7 machines.

Is there any solution to this as it is very critical to my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to be more useful.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/qz-print/6bSysyewN0k

There is an issue in windows XP java runtime which ignores **Caller-Allowable-Codebase**: **☆**, which was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javascript_applet.xml

The website uses JavaScript code in conjunction with the Java application. This message is shown to alert you of a possible security concern because the website was not explicitly granted access permission by the application.

To fix it on your end, use the Caller-Allowable-Codebase Attribute: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#caller_allowable

Edit: Btw, this is the first result for googling the exact text of the error. A little searching goes a long way.

Comment: I know this, but the error on the winXP machine is not correct. there is no application info in this dialog, and it keeps on prompting to allow every time I try to print.

Comment: What is not correct about it? Are you using JavaScript to interact with the applet?

Comment: The error dialog shown on winxp machine does not have this info about the applet, on win 7 it has the correct info. I'm not the developer of this applet. and it is not signed by me. Is there a way I can add **Caller-Allowable-Codebase** in the manifest without having to resign the applet?

Comment: I don't think so, but what happened when you tried? Are you using JavaScript to interact with the applet?

Comment: Yes, the javscript is required to execute the code. Clicking on allow does executes the required function, but I get a prompt again when I retry the function. It seems to me the issue with java 7u55 update on WindowsXP.

Comment: Then the "error message" is indeed correct, exactly as outlined in the Java documentation I linked to. You need to add the Caller-Allowable-Codebase to the manifest, and you need to re-sign your jar.

Comment: You are not paying attention, the just compare the screenshot that I have attached with the screenshot that java provides.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. You're asking why the warning messages don't look exactly the same. I think that's a minor issue, probably caused by the screenshots being generated using an older version of Java. I've provided you the steps to get rid of the warning message altogether, and you've chosen to ignore that advice. Good luck.